# Python - Tkinter - How delete all commands from a menu

Tags: python, tkinter, menu

It's all in the title. If I have this how can I reset my menu? (Thank you in advance for your help)

```py
menu = tk.Menu(root, tearoff = False)
menu.add_command(label="Open", command=Open)
menu.add_command(label="Close", command=Close)

menu.delete_all_commands() #magic function
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243873/discussion-on-question-by-ztf-python-tkinter-how-delete-all-commands-from-a).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the .delete() method, which takes two arguments: index1 (where to start deleting) and index2 (where to stop deleting) and then use the common 0, "end" heuristic to work this out. So:

```
menu.delete(0, "end")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to iterate it:

```
def delete_all_commands(menu : tkinter.Menu):
    try:
        for i in range(0,menu.index("end")):
            menu.delete("end")
    except:
        None
```

Comment: an explanation would be helpful.

Comment: Why is there the line `i += 1` inside `for i in ...`?

Comment: yeap sorry  the line `i += 1`  is really useless :)

Comment: For an explanation, I delete each command from the end until I have no more

Comment: index("end") is 0 if there is 1 element... so you would need smth like: for _ in range(menu.index(tk.END) + 1)